# Посчитать кто куда сколько раз отправил по логу почтового сервера. Проверка наличие ключа в словаре не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Доброго времени суток. Возник вопрос. Есть файл отфильтрованный из лога почтового сервера:

```
gpk@site.com  for 716745165214@kdf.net kglk@mail.ru lkjl@list.ru ncv@gmail.com
gpk@site.com  for 716745165214@kdf.net kglk@mail.ru lkjl@list.ru ncv@gmail.com
gpk@site.com  for 716745165214@kdf.net kglk@mail.ru lkjl@list.ru ncv@gmail.com
```

**Ожидаемый результат:**

```
{gpk@site.com
{
16745165214@kdf.net : 3
kglk@mail.ru : 3
kjl@list.ru : 3
ncv@gmail.com : 3
}
}
```

пишу код: которое должен почитать кто куда сколько раз отправил.

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def reader(fname):
    d={}
    fromto={}
    df=[]

    file = open(fname,"r")
    for line in file:
#           print (line)
            ll=line.strip().split('for')
            sfrom=''.join(ll[0].split())
            sto=ll[1].split()
            if sfrom in fromto: # почему-то проверка не рботает
                df = fromto[sfrom]

            for i in range(len(sto)):
                    df.append(sto[i])

            fromto[sfrom]= df
            df.clear()

    print(fromto)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reader('list-100.list')
```

Comment: 1) Добавьте отладку, хотя бы print'ами чтобы видеть что в коде происходит 2) Добавьте в вопрос еще пару строк примера и что должно получиться из них 3) у вас странные манипуляции с `df`, то его заполняете, то очищаете, причем все время один и тот же список используется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще разделять строку не по "for", а сразу по пробелам, и игнорировать второй элемент массива, который содержит "for".

Если необходимо еще и посчитать кто кому сколько раз отправил, то можно сделать так:

```
from collections import Counter

log = """\
gpk@site.com  for 716745165214@kdf.net kglk@mail.ru lkjl@list.ru ncv@gmail.com
gpk2@site.com  for 7167451652142@kdf.net kglk2@mail.ru lkjl2@list.ru ncv2@gmail.com
gpk@site.com  for 716745165214@kdf.net kglk@mail.ru lkjl@list.ru ncv@gmail.com
"""

pairs = Counter()
for line in log.splitlines():
    tmp = line.split()
    from_user = tmp[0]
    pairs.update((from_user, to_user) for to_user in tmp[2:])

print(pairs)
```

В итоге для каждой пары (Отправитель, Получатель) мы имеем число отправленных сообщений.

**UPD:**

При необходимости последующего вывода, *сгруппированного по отправителю*, можно использовать другой метод:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

base = defaultdict(Counter)

log = """gpk@site.com  for 716745165214@kdf.net kglk@mail.ru lkjl@list.ru ncv@gmail.com
gpk2@site.com  for 7167451652142@kdf.net kglk2@mail.ru lkjl2@list.ru ncv2@gmail.com
gpk@site.com  for 716745165214@kdf.net kglk@mail.ru lkjl@list.ru ncv@gmail.com
"""

for line in log.splitlines():
    tmp = line.split()
    from_user = tmp[0]
    base[from_user].update(tmp[2:])
```

и распечатка будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
for from_user, msgs in base.items():
    print("{0}:".format(from_user))
    for to_user, count_messages in msgs.items():
        print("    {0}: {1}".format(to_user, count_messages))
```

**Вывод консоли:**

```
gpk@site.com:
    716745165214@kdf.net: 2
    kglk@mail.ru: 2
    lkjl@list.ru: 2
    ncv@gmail.com: 2
gpk2@site.com:
    7167451652142@kdf.net: 1
    kglk2@mail.ru: 1
    lkjl2@list.ru: 1
    ncv2@gmail.com: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = """\
1. gpk@site.com  for 716745165214@kdf.net kglk@mail.ru lkjl@list.ru ncv@gmail.com
2. abc@site.com  for site@site.ru lkjl@list.com
"""

from_by_to_list = defaultdict(list)

for line in text.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    from_str, to_str = line.split('for')

    from_str = from_str.strip().split()[1]
    to_list = to_str.strip().split()

    from_by_to_list[from_str] += to_list

print(from_by_to_list)
print()

for k, items in from_by_to_list.items():
    print('{} ({}):'.format(k, len(items)))
    for i, x in enumerate(items, 1):
        print('    {}. {}'.format(i, x))

    print()
```

Консоль:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'gpk@site.com': ['716745165214@kdf.net', 'kglk@mail.ru', 'lkjl@list.ru', 'ncv@gmail.com'], 'abc@site.com': ['site@site.ru', 'lkjl@list.com']})

gpk@site.com (4):
    1. 716745165214@kdf.net
    2. kglk@mail.ru
    3. lkjl@list.ru
    4. ncv@gmail.com

abc@site.com (2):
    1. site@site.ru
    2. lkjl@list.com
```